# Is it illegal to lie and say you're under an NDA?

Tags: first-amendment, non-disclosure

Is lying about being under a non-disclosure agreement illegal?

Imagine that A manages a bunch of gaming servers online, and B keeps bugging A for information that A does not want to disclose. If A lies and says he's under an NDA, has he violated the law?

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, no.

Assuming your lie did not cause some "legally cognizable harm" -- as in the case of perjury, defamation, fraud -- it is almost certainly protected by the First Amendment. [*United States v. Alvarez*, 567 U.S. 709 (2012)](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/567/709/).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [scant] information you provide, you are fine.

Your description nowhere reflects that you have a duty to disclose to that person (1) the information he is trying to gather from you, or (2) whether or not you made any arrangements/agreements with third parties. Accordingly, your false statement is not actionable.

By contrast, [that person's retaliatory attempts to harm your reputation](https://law.stackexchange.com/revisions/57380/1) might render him liable for defamation and --depending on his method of defaming you-- possibly other torts.